# number of ways of arranging balls so that there are exactly two pairs of green balls

Tags: combinatorics, logic

There are $5$ identical red balls and $6$ identical green balls. In how manys we can arrange them so that there are exactly two pairs of green balls.

Let red balls be $R,R,R,R,R$ and green be $G,G,G,G,G,G$ and since we need exactly two pairs of green balls, let $X=GG$ and $Y=GG$.

Now it means we need to arrange $R,R,R,R,R,X,Y,G,G$ such that $X,Y,G,G$ should not be together.

So possibilities are

$*X*Y*G*G*$

(OR)

$**X*Y*G*G$

(OR)

$X*Y*G*G**$

where stars can be occupied by red balls.

So total ways is $$3 \times \frac{4!}{2!2!}=18$$ since $X$ and $Y$ are also identical.

Is this approach fine?

Comment: Is $GGGG$ two pairs? Is $GGG$ two pairs?

Comment: You forgot the case X* *Y*G*G* and other similar cases. It would be better if you inserted G,G,X,X into the gaps between the red balls. (also, X=Y). Like AndréNicolas said, the question does not make it clear what constitutes a pair, so the answer's gonna vary according to the way people count pairs

Comment: I think Its $40$

Comment: I meant X\*\*Y\*G\*G\*

Comment: the questions says $GG$ and $GG$ pairs should be there. if we take $GGGG$ it has three pairs. as andre nicholas said i forgot to count $GGG$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two pairs of green balls can be realized either (a) as two separate $G^2$ or (b) with one $G^3$. Therefore write the five $R$s with  spaces around and between them:
$$\ \underline{\ }\ R\ \underline{\ }\ R\ \underline{\ }\ R\ \underline{\ }\ R\ \underline{\ }\ R\ \underline{\ }\quad.$$
For (a) choose two slots for a $G^2$ each and then two of the remaining slots for a single $G$ each.

For (b) choose one slot for $G^3$ and then three of the remaining slots for a single $G$ each.

The total number of possibilites therefore comes to
$${6\choose 2}\cdot{4\choose 2}+{6\choose 1}\cdot{5\choose3}=150\ .$$

Comment: that was perfect thank you